# PHP do something if $var contains value

Tags: php, json, xml

I have a PHP variable which contains sometime while in a foreach loop.

```
{"@attributes":{"name":"betrag"},"0":"56.82"}
```

It is filled by using `json_encode` to see the values "name" and "betrag".

Now I wand to create an `if` when the `$var` contains `betrag` to put the `int` in another `$var`, but it never succeeds.

I guess it's a simple solution, but I don't get it.

Having an XML as datasource where fields all have the same names but at least a description which I can see when doing "json_encode". But unable to work out how to trigger if the searched string is true to put some int inside the $var.

Comment: `it never succeeds`...well what did you try? You didn't show us. See [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. We can't fix vaguely-described problems in invisible code.

Comment: But honestly it's quite difficult to understand what the difficulty could really be. Simply decode the JSON and check the value - demo: https://3v4l.org/tmgXp . P.S. It's unclear how this relates to XML - all you've shown us is JSON. I didn't understand that part of your question.

Comment: Are you using `json_encode()` on an XML API (SimpleXML)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourJsonResponse = '{"@attributes":{"name":"betrag"},"0":"56.82"}';

// decode your JSon String and convert to Array
$decodedResult = json_decode($yourJsonResponse,true);

// sample Output - only for debug:
echo '<textarea>';
print_r($decodedResult);
echo '</textarea><br>';
echo $decodedResult['@attributes']['name'] . '<br>';    // Output: betrag
echo $decodedResult[0] . '<br>';                        // Output: 56.82

// your condidion if your Json String contains "betrag"
if ( (isset($decodedResult['@attributes']['name'])) AND ($decodedResult['@attributes']['name']== 'betrag') ) {
    echo 'betrag was found...';
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: "Maybe"...why? Don't ask us to guess or hope...that just encourages cargo-cult coding and blind copying. Explain why it's helpful and solves the problem, and therefore why we should bother with it. See also [answer] . Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to the commuity and I only want to help... Everytime someone new try to help somebody else - there is a problem. Why?

Comment: Please *explain* the code. How does this solve the issue at hand? Keep in mind you are also posting for future-readers looking for a possible answer to a similar question

Comment: @DarkBee Ok. I try to update my Answer in the correct way. I have edited and updated my answer. One Question about it: Is that ok for now, or do I have to seperate the comments outside and better split it into seperate text- / codeblocks block by block?

Comment: `there is a problem. Why`...I think I explained that in my first comment. There's nothing wrong with wanting to help, but you need to do it in a way that's actually useful, as we explained. I see you've updated the post now, and it's a little better, although some text which isn't just inline comments, summarising the situation and what you've done, would also be good. Go and look at some highly upvoted answers on the site and see how they structure their posts. And did you read [answer]?

Comment: I don't think you need to split the code blocks in this case...that can often make it incoherent anyway, actually. A summary of the approach, and then the inline comments should be sufficient. Thanks for updating it.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for explain how to do it better and thank you for removing the downvote. I saw the question, and just prepared an answer because I had a similar problem last week. But then there was an error submitting my answer and about 5 minutes later I got 2 downvotes... But OK - I understand - This is not compareable to other forums. I will try to answer in the correct way in the future and I read the "how to answer" again. Thank you for undersanding and supporting me.